# throw an error inside a case_when()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `case_when()` inside a `mutate()` and I'd like R to stop and throw an error if the `TRUE` condition is fulfilled. This is for debugging purposes.

For example, values for mtcars$cyl are 4, 6 or 8. With the proper solution in place in the fourth line, this should be able to run without error:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(test = case_when(
    cyl > 3 ~ "ok",
    TRUE ~ # code for throwing error here
  ))
```

This should throw the error:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(test = case_when(
    cyl < 3 ~ "ok",
    TRUE ~ # code for throwing error here
  ))
```

I tried `stop` but this triggers the exception even if `TRUE` is never fulfilled.

Comment: Are you trying to stop if any value is less than 3 ?.  Not clear about the expected output

Comment: from doc: `all RHSs must evaluate to the same type of vector.`

Comment: yes, I just want to trigger an error if any value is less than 3. It's for debugging purposes. In my actual situation I have a set of conditions that are designed to cover all possibilities, so I want an interruption if there's a case I didn't think of (which is what would be captured by `TRUE`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in the `case_when` call as far as I understand, because all RHSs will be evaluated beforehand to make sure they're of the same type.

You could do this however :

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(test = case_when(
    cyl > 3 ~ "ok",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ),
  test=if (anyNA(test)) stop() else test
  )
```

or

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(test = case_when(
    cyl > 3 ~ "ok",
    TRUE ~ "STOP_VALUE"
  ),
  test=if ("STOP_VALUE" %in% test) stop() else test
  )
```