# Stopping execution if case_when finds a certain result

Tags: r, error-handling, case-when

From [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when):

```
x <- 1:50
case_when(
  x %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
  x %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
  x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  TRUE ~ as.character(x)
)
```

How can I use **stop()** to stop execution as soon as I get an x divisible by 6? I do not want multiple error messages, just one.

Comment: Here, the ones used are 35, 5, 7.  Do you want to use 10 replaced by one of those ?

Comment: I don't think `case_when` is structured to allow incomplete evaluation on the vector; you'll likely need to write something yourself.

Comment: @akrun good point. Let me change that to divisible by 6.

Comment: when you use `stop`, it would return as an error.  I guess you want the output vector before the stop, right?  Do you only want a solution with `case_when` or are you okay with other solutions?

Comment: This seems to apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086562/ as @r2evans mentions, why not a simple for loop and if statement? `for (i in 1:length(x)) {
   if(x[[i]] %% 6 == 0) {
      print(i)
      stop("Found it")
   }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the internals of `case_when`, you'll realize that it is executing each vector in order of the vectors, not in order of the data. That is, in your example, your first expression `x %% 35 == 0` evaluates for the entire length of `x` before the function even looks at your second expression, `x %% 5 == 0`. It evaluates all of the expressions (LHS) and only then starts checking for matches. So there is no short-circuiting the evaluation of your data.

If you're not worried about over-calculation and just want to truncate your data, then

```r
x <- 1:50
ret <- case_when(
  x %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
  x %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
  x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  TRUE ~ as.character(x)
)
ret[!cumany(x %% 6 == 0)]
# [1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "fizz"
```

If you want/need to stay within the `case_when` call, then perhaps

```r
x <- 1:50
ret <- case_when(
  cumany(x %% 6 == 0) ~ NA_character_,
  x %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
  x %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
  x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
  TRUE ~ as.character(x)
)
ret
#  [1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "fizz" NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
# [18] NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    
# [35] NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    

## filtered
na.omit(ret)
# [1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "fizz"
# attr(,"na.action")
#  [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
# [40] 45 46 47 48 49 50
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "omit"

## or more succinctly
ret[!is.na(ret)]
# [1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "fizz"
```

for which you can then `na.omit` or similar. But again, this is not interrupting or short-circuiting, so absolutely no savings in execution time. (And no ability to feed an infinitely-large vector with the assumption that it'll interrupt itself when one of the `%% 6` conditions is found.)

In order to short-circuit evaluation of the LHS, you will need to break the vectorized evaluation of `case_when` and do everything yourself. Unfortunately, there is a "problem": the way that `case_when` maintains generality is by evaluating each LHS expression (and RHS, for that matter) in the context of the calling environment. For instance, it evaluates `x %% 35 == 0` in the parent frame (i.e., the environment that called `case_when`). The `case_when` function has no idea a priori how long the returned vector will be, nor how to correctly index (step through) any and all of the variables present. For instance, it seems intuitive that with `x %% 35 == 0` we would want to first check `x[1] %% 35 == 0`, then `x[2] %% 35 == 0`, etc ... but what about `(x+y) %% 35 == 0` where `y` might be a vector of the same length, a recycled vector of a divisible length, or a single value, where `(x[50]+y[50]) %% 35 == 0` would result in an `NA` (or index error).

Here's a way to wrap around `case_when` and only evaluate until the constraint is found, then stop.

```r
x <- 1:50
ret <- numeric(length(x))
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  # constraint
  if (x[i] %% 6 == 0) break
  # regular piece-wise execution
  ret[i] <- case_when(
    x[i] %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
    x[i] %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
    x[i] %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
    TRUE ~ as.character(x[i])
  )
}
ret <- head(ret, i - 1)
ret
# [1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "fizz"
```

This loop iterates 6 times, where the first 5 are executed normally, and on the 6th iteration it finds that `x[i] %% 6 == 0` is true, and `break`s.

---

I would be remiss if I didn't address the relative (in)efficiency of these methods.

```r
x <- 1:50
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  one = {
    ret <- case_when(
      x %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
      x %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
      x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
      TRUE ~ as.character(x)
    )
    ret[!cumany(x %% 6 == 0)]
  },
  two = {
    ret <- case_when(
      cumany(x %% 6 == 0) ~ NA_character_,
      x %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
      x %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
      x %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
      TRUE ~ as.character(x)
    )
    ret[!is.na(ret)]
  },
  three = {
    ret <- numeric(length(x))
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      # constraint
      if (x[i] %% 6 == 0) break
      # regular piece-wise execution
      ret[i] <- case_when(
        x[i] %% 35 == 0 ~ "fizz buzz",
        x[i] %% 5 == 0 ~ "fizz",
        x[i] %% 7 == 0 ~ "buzz",
        TRUE ~ as.character(x[i])
      )
    }
    ret <- head(ret, i - 1)
  }
)
# Unit: microseconds
#   expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#    one  136.6  143.55  168.975  152.60  167.55   478.3   100
#    two  156.9  171.10  199.213  180.05  206.80   427.3   100
#  three 4772.7 5336.75 5854.889 5605.25 6073.20 12001.8   100
```

It should be clear here that with this set of expressions (a few modulus operations), in R it is far more efficient to calculate more than we need but use a vectorized approach than it is to try to limit how much of `x` we process.

If you're curious, this `third` method is still not efficient when `x` is 500K long ...

```r
x <- 1:500
# Unit: microseconds
#   expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#    one  216.9  245.5  287.715  261.55  289.20   601.4   100
#    two  220.9  260.8  300.539  277.75  295.75   691.5   100
#  three 5578.7 6164.9 6802.093 6531.20 6884.25 13667.9   100
x <- 1:5000
# Unit: microseconds
#   expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
#    one 1468.2 1644.50 3809.862 1708.65 1879.90 196632.1   100
#    two  780.9  852.25  986.799  889.90  952.45   6761.6   100
#  three 8061.9 8785.15 9836.741 9249.85 9803.70  17088.5   100
x <- 1:50000
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    one 15.9505 20.33195 26.18902 22.60755 26.75880 230.6372   100
#    two  6.8114  8.33300 12.92443  8.95825 14.18375 236.4153   100
#  three 34.6127 43.44130 48.28222 47.23290 53.26485  71.2169   100
x <- 1:500000
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    one 201.1099 220.5286 278.7940 238.9214 280.8388 548.7299   100
#    two  82.8113 104.9474 139.0557 118.3804 136.0794 380.3658   100
#  three 295.7582 310.8903 335.8939 322.4250 349.4466 567.1915   100
```

But finally reaches some parity at 5M:

```r
x <- 1:5000000
# Unit: seconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    one 2.713632 2.794410 3.371636 3.175023 3.820303 4.682576    10
#    two 1.105257 1.278336 1.535301 1.371372 1.854551 2.281774    10
#  three 3.082974 3.116061 3.292641 3.314118 3.476838 3.513049    10
```

(This will vary significantly as the computation-cost changes.)